# Por que muesta al ejecutar el login Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in

Tags: php, sql-server

```
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];

        include_once "usuario.php";

        $usuario = new Usuario();
        $usuario->setusername($username);
        $resultados = $usuario->mostrarUsuarios();

        if($resultados){
            $passwordDB = $resultados["passwordusu"];
         
            if($password == $passwordDB){
                header("location: paginausu.php");
            } else {
                echo "Usuario y/o Contraseña incorrectos";
            }
        } else {
                echo "Usuario y/o Contraseña incorrectos";
        }
    }
```

> Por que da en error  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array
> cuando se ejecuta en resultado passwordusu es la variable que esta en base de datos cual seria el error

```
   public function mostrarUsuarios(){
        $myConn = $this->conexion();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
        $resultados = $myConn->query($sql);
        $this->cerrar();

        return $resultados;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podríamos decir que en el mensaje de error está la solución: *`Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array`* te está diciendo que un resultado de mysqli no puede ser usado como un array.

Hay algo que es **muy importante** entender: cuando ejecutas una consulta con `mysqli` lo que recibes es un recurso, algo así como un puntero hacia los datos. Pero ese recurso no puedes devolverlo desde el contexto de la consulta a otra parte, la conexión debe estar activa al momento de leer los datos y cuando haces `return` la conexión se cierra y no podrías leer el recurso.

Aparte de eso, necesitas un array. Para obtenerlo, tienes que leer el recurso, recorrer el puntero fila por fila con un método adecuado e ir metiendo cada fila en un array. Y finalmente devolver ese array.

El problema debería resolverse haciendo esto:

```
   public function mostrarUsuarios(){
        $myConn = $this->conexion();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
        $resultados = $myConn->query($sql);
        $mArray=array();
        while ($fila = $resultados->fetch_assoc()) {
            #Aquí cada fila se guardará en $mArray de forma asociativa
            $mArray[]=$fila;
    }
        $this->cerrar();
        return $mArray;
    }
```

Ahí si estarías leyendo el recurso con el método `fetch_assoc()`, el bucle `while` va moviendo el puntero fila por fila y guardando cada fila en el array final. Ten en cuenta lo dicho en el segundo párrafo: los recursos que te devuelve mysqli deben ser impresos o leídos/guardados in situ, no fuera del contexto donde se obtienen.

Comment: El error se soluciona pero $resultados["passwordusu"] no reconoce dice que es undefinide a que se debe eso

Comment: @CristhianChavezAlonso debes verificar cómo se llama la columna realmente y usar el nombre exacto de la misma.

Comment: passwordusu varchar(128), la columna se llama "passwordusu" y aun asi no da tambien verifique con var_dump() y devuelve  ["passwordusu"]=> string(6) "123456" y no encuentro a que se debe el error

Comment: @CristhianChavezAlonso haz un `var_dump($resultados);` Ten en cuenta que estás recibiendo un array de filas, por tanto debes recorrer dicho array. Si esperas una sola fila, entonces es preciso aclararlo en la pregunta.